# how to remove the cloth pattern in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

I am trying to remove the entire pattern from the cloth. I need the output like the attached image.

Comment: Tricky, if you still want to include the shadows and wrinkles and preserve everything else.

Comment: Yes, I need to retain shadows and wrinkles everything

Comment: http://creatingawebstore.com/how-to-change-the-color-of-clothing-using-photoshop.html

Comment: The above you mentioned website shows the Photoshop method

Comment: Exactly.  Photoshop them, and then use multiple images.

Comment: Or can we adjust the color?

Comment: Sure, but you'll still have the grid pattern on the shirt.  This isn't as easy as you think it is.

Comment: Might be rather simpler if your “input” didn’t have a pattern? Hang on, the output image is the perfect input for the rest of your process, isn’t it?